# JSON column in Laravel does not receive values of others columns

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a json that collects all the information from the other columns, but the following error happens when I create a new record:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'properties' doesn't have a default value`

- `Migration`

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hunters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name_hunter', 50);
            $table->integer('year_hunter');
            $table->decimal('height_hunter', 3,2);
            $table->decimal('weight_hunter', 5,2);
            $table->string('type_hunter', 30);
            $table->string('type_nen', 30);
            $table->string('type_sangue', 3);
            $table->timestamp('register_date')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('data_updated')->useCurrent()->useCurrentOnUpdate();
            $table->json('properties');
        });
    }
```

- `HunterModel.php`

```
    protected $casts = [
        'properties' => 'array'
    ];
```

- `HunterController.php`

```
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }
    
    public function store(HunterRequest $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();
        HunterModel::create($validations);
        return redirect('/');   
    }
```

- `create.php`

```
<form action="{{ url("create") }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form_group">
        <div for="nome_hunter">Name:
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name_hunter" maxlength="50" value="{{ old('name_hunter') }}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    ...                
    <div class="form_group">
        <div for="type_blood">Type blood:
            <select class="form-control" name="type_blood">
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == '' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="">Choose the type blood</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'A+' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="A+">A+</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'A-' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="A-">A-</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'B+' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="B+">B+</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'B-' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="B-">B-</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'AB+' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="AB+">AB+</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'AB-' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="AB-">AB-</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'O+' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="O+">O+</option>
                <option {{ old('type_blood') == 'O-' ? 'selected' : ''}} value="O-">O-</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

What is the necessary change in the form so that it is possible for the JSON to collect the information?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... where is your code to do the insert?

Comment: @lagbox is in ```HunterController.php```.

Comment: and where are you assigning all those values to the key 'properties' to insert? also that field would have to be fillable

Answer (score 0):

You need a default value for the properties field. Add this to your migration and re-run it (be sure to revert the last migration).

```
$table->json('properties')->default(json_encode([]));
```

Comment: I want to add the values of the other fields in it. Would I have to change something in the form fields?

Comment: Your issue was the SQL part, which is now fixed by the updated migration. For the new issue open a new question with the form and ask a specific question about storing the data. If the sql error has been fixed mark the answer as correct and proceed with a new question.